# Why can't set font according to language?

Tags: debian, fonts, fontconfig

OS and desktop environment info:

```
uname -a
Linux debian 5.10.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.140-1 (2022-09-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
sudo dpkg -s lxde | grep Version
Version: 11
sudo dpkg -s lxappearance | grep Version
Version: 0.6.3-1+b1
```

Below setting is my font configuration in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/fontconfig/fonts.conf`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "urn:fontconfig:fonts.dtd">
<!-- $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/fontconfig/fonts.conf for per-user font configuration -->
<fontconfig>    
<dir prefix="xdg">fonts</dir>    
<match target="font">
    <edit name="rgba" mode="assign"><const>rgb</const></edit>
</match>
<match>
    <test name="lang" compare="eq">
        <string>en_US</string>
    </test>
    <edit name="family" mode="assign">
        <string>Hack</string>
    </edit>
</match>    
<match>
    <test name="lang" compare="eq">
        <string>zh_CN</string>
    </test>
    <edit name="family" mode="assign">
        <string>Noto Sans CJK SC</string>
    </edit>
</match>
</fontconfig>
```

My target is to render character with `Hack`(a kind of font often used by coder `https://github.com/source-foundry/Hack`) when language is English,and render character with `Noto Sans CJK SC` when language is Chinese.
You see i have set `Hack` as the default font in terminal.

[image: setting in terminal]

Now i type some English character and Chinese character in the terminal,you can see the English letter is rendered by `Hack` font.I am sure the Chinese word is not rendered as desired,it is not `Noto Sans CJK SC`.

[image: typed characters in terminal]

The word in `Noto Sans CJK SC` font should be as below:

[image: proof--the word is not rendered by Noto Sans CJK SC in my terminal]

What is the strange font?How to fix it?